# 500 - internal server error my API is not working

Tags: javascript, mongoose, next.js

I make a crud with products

I send an http request to the /api/deleteProduct route with the product id to retrieve it on the server side and delete the product by its id

To create a product it works only the delete does not work

pages/newProduct.js :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/products');
      setProducts(res.data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('picture', picture);
  formData.append('name', name);
  formData.append('price', price);
  formData.append('category', category);
  formData.append('description', description);
  try {
  const res = await axios.post('/api/createProduct', formData);
  console.log(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }
  };
  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/deleteProduct?id=${id}`);
      setProducts(products.filter(product => product._id !== id));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

api/deleteProduct.js :

```js
import Product from '../../models/Products';
import { initMongoose } from '../../lib/mongoose';

initMongoose();

export const handleDelete = async (req, res) => {

  if (req.method === 'DELETE'){
  try {
 
    const { id } = req.params
    
    const product = await Product.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    if (!product) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Product not found' });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Product deleted successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Database error' });
  }
}};
```

I have a 500 error but no error in the server side console and the console.log is not showing like the file was not read

Comment: maybe you can add your routes file.
and to help you more, you should use rest api pattern for your api.

something like that:


GET /products - Retrieve a list of all products
GET /products/{id} - Retrieve a specific product by its ID
POST /products - Create a new product
PUT /products/{id} - Update an existing product
DELETE /products/{id} - Delete a specific product

Comment: Yes its true when i have solved the problem i will name my routes to use rest api pattern but i am using nextjs so the routes of my files match the name of the files @FilipePrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded, I put this (server side):

> const { id } = req. query;

and (client side):

> await axios.delete(`/api/deleteProduct?id=${id}`);

and I exported my function like this:

> export default async function handleDelete(req, res) {

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code you've shared, it seems that the problem may be with the way that the delete request is being handled on the frontend. Specifically, in this line:

```
await axios.delete("/api/deleteProduct", { params: { id } });
```

The delete request is supposed to receive the id of the product that should be deleted as a query parameter, but it is being passed as a request body.

Instead of passing it as a parameter, you should pass it as a query parameter by changing it to

```
await axios.delete(`/api/deleteProduct?id=${id}`);
```

Also, in your api/deleteProduct.js, you should change the following line:

```
const { id } = req.query;
```

to
const { id } = req.params;

Also, you should make sure that the server is running and that the api endpoint '/api/deleteProduct' is accessible and handling the request correctly.

For the last, make sure that the product model is imported and initialized correctly and the database connection is established.

Hope that it solves your problem or, at least, helps :))

Comment: I corrected that but I still have a 500 error, and I have the following error "resolver is not a function" in the server side console on the page: /api/deleteProduct

Comment: and the model as well as the connection to the database are well initialized

Comment: Mmmmmhh..  It seems like the issue is that you are trying to use a function called "handleDelete" in your API route '/api/deleteProduct' which is not a function, it is a constant.
It's possible that you have defined this function somewhere else in your code, but it is not being imported correctly in the file where you are trying to use it. Check that the file where you define your handleDelete function is imported correctly in the file where you are using it. Also ensure that the function name is spelled correctly and that you are calling it correctly.

Comment: Also check that you are importing the correct handleDelete function, since it seems that you have different handleDelete function in different files.